# Selenium Webdriver on Google Cloud instance won't load a certain URL I need

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, google-cloud-platform

The call to

```
driver.get()
```

never finishes. I've tried using both Chrome and PhantomJS, but this URL (and other similar ones) just won't load on either. URLs on other sites work fine. Cloud instance is running Ubuntu 16.04, and I've configured Webdriver properly.

This same code works fine on my own laptop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import time

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://api.flightradar24.com/common/v1/flight/list.json?query=vt-iao&fetchBy=reg&page=1&limit=100&token=')
#driver.get('http://www.google.com')
# ^works
```

EDIT: I actually have some other Selenium code that is not able to finish loading a page that requests this particular URL. The above code is just to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using Selenium to consume API instead of requests?

Comment: I could use requests for this particular URL, but I already have some Selenium code that deals with the UI of the main site. That code was not working because of this particular request (and other similar ones to the API).

Comment: Are you able to browse to the URL https://api.flightradar24.com/common/v1/flight/list.json?query=vt-iao&fetchBy=reg&page=1&limit=100&token=  manually? Can you consider accessing the base URL `https://api.flightradar24.com/` first & then gradually proceed to the intended URI through calling `click()` method? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB I can access the URL from my laptop. From the Google cloud instance, no (using curl command). Going to base URL and using `click()` is not possible.

Comment: @MichalK curl command also does not work on that URL from the cloud instance

Comment: Lets assume, the page loads, so what actions are you going to do next? Rememeber it's a JSON file. Thanks